# How to install "graphics" python library/module in the Python IDE Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder, python-3.5

I'm using Spyder to make some physics applications my teacher ask me to make a graphic interface. Previously I used graphics in python 3.5 to create simple windows to my projects. Now im trying to do this in Spyder, but when im using the graphics module methods Spyder says that is not defined.

P.D. Sorry for bad english im trying to improve.

Answer (score 2):

Simply download [`graphics.py`](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) and move the file to your Python installation's `site-packages` folder. Restart Spyder and you should be all set.

Comment: I do that but when I want to use a method from graphics Spyder marks an error saying that graphics is imported but unused.

Comment: Well of course it will be unused when you first import it! Even though it's terribly bad form, most tutorials I've seen with `graphics.py` say you should have `from graphics import *`, then use the various classes and methods as-is. The Pythonic way is to use either `from graphics import Class1, Class2, Class3` if those are the only classes you'll be using, or, more simply, either use `import graphics` and refer to the classes as `graphics.Class1`, etc., or shortcut your typing by using `import graphics as gr` and refer to its classes with `gr.Class1`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply download graphics.py from http://nifty.stanford.edu/2013/denero-muralidharan-trends/graphics.py.html then find .spyder-py3 folder from your computer like C:\Users\CSE.spyder-py3  then paste the file graphics.py under .spyder-py3 folder.Now you will be capable  to import graphics in spyder IDE.